# Why is Astro JS Dynamic Routing returning 404 always on my local dev environment?

Tags: astrojs, dynamic-routing

I am building an Astro JS application and trying to use the Dynamic Routing as described [here](https://thevalleyofcode.com/astro/5-dynamic-routing), but for some reason, it is not working at all locally and always returns the Astro JS 404 page. This is my code:

```
---
import Layout from '../layouts/Layout.astro'
const { article } = Astro.params;

export function getStaticPaths() {
    return [
      { params: { article: 'text' } }
    ]
}
---
<Layout title=`Polarix.io | ${article}`>
  <h1 style="color: black">{article}</h1>
</Layout>
```

I am running my site locally using the `npx astro dev` command in my terminal, and my target page is `[article].astro`, which is in `src/pages` as per the post above.

The URL I am calling in the browser is `http://localhost:4321/article/text`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: url should be http://localhost:4321/text
see also official docs: https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/routing/#dynamic-routes